# A Story/ Movie about a Robot Boy from ca. 2005-2009

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, movie

I just recently remembered that when I was still in elementary school (ca. 2005-2009), a teacher talked about a new Science Fiction story or movie they had recently read/ seen, and now I can't get it out of my head - unfortunately, I can't recall much.

From what little I can remember, it played in the near future and was about a man who constructed (or bought?) a sentient robot boy for his wife as a replacement for their dead son.

However, for some reason I can't recall, the boy is kicked out (by the "father"?), but keeps with him a strand of hair of his "mother". I think afterwards a lot of stuff happens to the robot, and at some point the "mother" dies (if I remember correctly, there has been a war).

In the end, however, the robot can revive his mother with the DNA that can be extracted out of the strand of hair he kept with him.

Comment: AI (2001), Spielberg

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi You're right! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ***[A.I. Artificial Intelligence](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/?ref_=ttpl_ov)*** (2001)...?

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/AIArtificialIntelligence):

> *A.I.: Artificial Intelligence* is a 2001 American Science Fiction film written and directed by Steven Spielberg. Adapted from the Brian Aldiss short story "Super-Toys Last All Summer Long", the film notably originated as a project by Stanley Kubrick before he eventually personally handed it over to Spielberg.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence):

> **In Madison, New Jersey, David, a prototype Mecha child capable of experiencing love, is given to Henry Swinton and his wife Monica, whose son Martin contracted a rare disease and has been placed in suspended animation. Monica initially feels uneasy with David, but eventually warms to him and activates his imprinting protocol, causing him to have an enduring, childlike love for her.** David seeks to have Monica express the same love towards him, and also befriends Teddy, Martin's robotic teddy bear. Martin is unexpectedly cured of his disease and brought home. Martin becomes jealous of David and goads him to perform worrisome acts, such as cutting off the locks of Monica's hair while she is sleeping.
>
> [...]
>
> **Two thousand years later, humanity has become extinct and Manhattan is now buried under glacial ice. Mecha have evolved into an advanced form, and a group of them called the Specialists have become interested in learning about humanity.** They find and revive David and Teddy. David walks to the frozen Blue Fairy statue, which collapses when he touches it. The Specialists reconstruct the Swinton family home from David's memories and explain to him, via an interactive image of the Blue Fairy, that it is impossible to make David a real boy. However, **at David's insistence, they use their scientific knowledge to recreate Monica through genetic material from the strand of hair that Teddy kept.**